# XQUERY/XSLT Advance Math

Tags: xml, xslt, math, xslt-2.0, xquery-3.0

I'm trying to perform a more advanced calculation in an XSLT/XQuery but running into an issue.  The formula is to aggregate sum but it performs operations before the sum.

Assuming we have XML source file of:

```
<day>
    <record>
        <time>2015-05-02 02:03:00-0400</time>
        <runtime>330</runtime>
        <level>51.6</level>
        <lvlmax>73.9</lvlmax>
        <lvlmin>45.1</lvlmin>
    </record>
    <record>
        <time>2015-05-02 02:18:00-0400</time>
        <runtime>215</runtime>
        <level>51.6</level>
        <lvlmax>83.9</lvlmax>
        <lvlmin>48.1</lvlmin>
    </record>
    <record>
        <time>2015-05-03 02:28:00-0400</time>
        <runtime>215</runtime>
        <level>51.6</level>
        <lvlmax>63.9</lvlmax>
        <lvlmin>40.1</lvlmin>
    </record>
</day>
```

This is the XPATH/XQUERY statment. Everything works except for 'level' calculation where we get a ***"Too many items, expected '1', '2' was supplied"*** error.  Each piece of the formula seems to work independently so I think the problem has to do with performing the operations on the values prior to performing the aggregation function.

```
let $hourly_records := distinct-values(//day/record/substring(time,1,13))
for $record in $hourly_records
return

        <day>   
            <time>{concat($record,':00:00-0500')}</time>    
            <runtime>{sum(//day/record[$record eq substring(time,1,13)]/runtime)}</runtime>
            <level>{20*math:log10(sum(math:exp10(//day/record[$record eq substring(time,1,13)]/level div 20)))}</level>     
            <lvlmax>{max(//day/record[$record eq substring(time,1,13)]/lvlmax)}</lvlmax>
            <lvllmin>{min(//day/record[$record eq substring(time,1,13)]/lvlmin)}</lvllmin>
        </day>
```

I've used SQL to perform this and it would perform the calculation correctly.  It would look something like this:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('hour', time) as htime,
  sum(runtime) as runtime,
  20*log10(sum(10^(level/10)) as level,
  max(lvlmax) as lvlmax,
  min(lvlmin) as lvlmin
FROM 
  thisXML
GROUP BY 
  htime
```

Anyways, I'm at a loss on how get this to work.  I welcome thoughts and comments and hope its not something so simple I look ridiculous... :) lol

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you might want or what at least is possible with XQuery:

```
declare namespace math = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math";
let $hourly_records := distinct-values(//day/record/substring(time,1,13))
for $record in $hourly_records
return

        <day>   
            <time>{concat($record,':00:00-0500')}</time>    
            <runtime>{sum(//day/record[$record eq substring(time,1,13)]/runtime)}</runtime>
            <level>{20*math:log10(sum(//day/record[$record eq substring(time,1,13)]/level/math:exp10((. div 20))))}</level>     
            <lvlmax>{max(//day/record[$record eq substring(time,1,13)]/lvlmax)}</lvlmax>
            <lvllmin>{min(//day/record[$record eq substring(time,1,13)]/lvlmin)}</lvllmin>
        </day>
```

Result is

```
<day>
   <time>2015-05-02 02:00:00-0500</time>
   <runtime>545</runtime>
   <level>57.62059991327963</level>
   <lvlmax>83.9</lvlmax>
   <lvllmin>45.1</lvllmin>
</day>
<day>
   <time>2015-05-03 02:00:00-0500</time>
   <runtime>215</runtime>
   <level>51.6</level>
   <lvlmax>63.9</lvlmax>
   <lvllmin>40.1</lvllmin>
</day>
```

Comment: Ah... I see where I went wrong.  I just mixed up the order (for all intense purposes).  Thanks very much - your example helped me to understand the procedural difference in XPATH/XQUERY.